# Get records based on days laravel carbon

Tags: mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I want to get the records based on days for example

1) > 180 days = number of records created

2) 90 to 180 days = number of records created

3) 60 to 90 days =  number of records created

4) 30 to 60 days = number of records created

But I am not getting the exact result. Is this the correct way to do it?

what I have tried in the blade view

```
    <?php 
         $date1 =  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(180); 
         $date2 =  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(90);
         $date3 =  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(60);
         $date4 =  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
    ?> 

   in blade 


   {{ \App\Claim::where('created_at','>=', $date1)->count() }}

   {{ \App\Claim::where('created_at','>=', $date2)->where('created_at','<', $date1)->count() }}

   {{ \App\Claim::where('created_at','>=', $date3)->where('created_at','<', $date2)->count() }}

   {{ \App\Claim::where('created_at','>=', $date4)->where('created_at','<', $date3)->count() }}

   {{ \App\Claim::where('created_at','<=', $date4)->count() }}
```

Comment: First of all, I would recommend using [whereBetween()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: @kiprasT If I use whereBetween I am getting all records

Comment: `\App\Claim::whereBetween('created_at', [$date1, $date2])->count()` yields a count of all the records?

Comment: same things I have used but I am getting all records

Comment: @kiprasT {{ \App\Claim::whereBetween('created_at', [$date2, $date1])->count() }} this one I am using now

Comment: Provide examples of which data is counted when it should not be.

Comment: I have only 14 records. The result I am getting is > 180 = 14, 90-180 = 0, 60-90 =0, 30-60 =0, 0-30 = 8 wait I am updating my question  with the output what I am getting

Comment: What are their `created_at` field values?

Comment: yes, I am using created_at  column

Comment: i guess you have to minus each count from its` previous count.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... any example?

Comment: What output your are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
?php 
         $date1 =  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(180)->format('Y-m-d'); 
         $date2 =  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(90)->format('Y-m-d');
         $date3 =  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(60)->format('Y-m-d');
         $date4 =  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(30)->format('Y-m-d');
    ?> 

   in blade 

   {{ \App\Claim::whereDate('created_at','>=', $date1)->count() }}

   {{ \App\Claim::whereDate('created_at','>=', $date2)->whereDate('created_at','<', $date1)->count() }}

   {{ \App\Claim::whereDate('created_at','>=', $date3)->whereDate('created_at','<', $date2)->count() }}

   {{ \App\Claim::whereDate('created_at','>=', $date4)->whereDate('created_at','<', $date3)->count() }}

   {{ \App\Claim::whereDate('created_at','<=', $date4)->count() }}
```

Note : Make variables date format `Y-m-d`